# 9v Battery Recharge Circuit

Tags: batteries, current, charge

I want to have a battery bank of 9v rechargeables to power my system. I want to have the recharge circuit on the PCB.

My idea for the circuit is to linearly source current in reference to the deviation from 9v... That way it will trickle charge once the battery approaches full charge and I wont over charge the batterys if I leave the recharge source on.

Also, the charge current will be limited to whatever is recommended.

So my question is:

1. Is this a good recharging scheme?
2. What should I limit the max charging current to?
3. I've seen both NiMH and Li-Ion batterys, to they required different charging schemes?
4. Some batterys are 8.4v or something, will charging them to 9v damage them?

Thanks

Comment: There are well-established chemistry-specific charging profiles recommended by the battery manufacturers. I would suggest to follow them.

Comment: "I've seen both NiMH and Li-Ion batterys, to they required different charging schemes?" - The answer to that is a resounding YES. And since you had to ask, I would advice you that NiMH is much more forgiving and much safer. So for your own sake, stay away from Lithium batteries for now.

Comment: You should probably look into battery charger/manager ICs (Linear Technology is the first place I'd look).  It will be much easier and possibly less flammable.

Comment: @Dampmaskin I've had (very) extensive experience with NimH charging and am well acquainted with LiIon charging. While it's easy to get LiIon to do nasty things if you abuse them, the requirements for good safe charging are very well defined (unlike NimH) and easily met and ICs that handle the task well are readily available. Of the two I consider that LiIon is much easier for a beginner to use well. Following the rules is essential but usually not hard to achieve.

Comment: I'm going to use NiMH that way I can fully discharge the batterys without damaging them. What makes charging a battery so tricky? Do they have a delayed response to recharging? Most of the ICs pulse the current, is this better? And also monitor the batterys voltage response to make sure it is not negative. Do batterys start having an opposite reaction to charging when they start to fail or overcharged?